# Change resolution of the rendered view ?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

how the rendered view work ? we can change the preview sample , the preview bounce , the preview subdivision , the preview texture size , but can we change the render view resolution?

i have this feeling its stuck on the native resolution of the display which is really bad if you want to have a quick real timme preview (5k screen here)

if its not possible ill do a topic on right click select

Comment: What are you talking about with the "render view resolution" ? In Properties > Render > Sampling > Samples you can choose the Preview quality (Preview factor) and also the definitive Render quality (Render factor). Maybe you're talking about the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Itds "pixel size" option in propreties render tab , and its coming to 2.8

Comment: It’s also in 2.79.5